# Best ways to call Multiple Async task Fetch Data from Server to Local in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

1.In my android App more than 10 Asynctask is Available.

2.its using for Fetching Data from Server to Local DB.

i kept Async task in the Separate Class.

So Can i call Simultaneously Like mentioned Below. It will Create any Problem, While Syncing and Inserting in Local Database or else Suggest me any other Solution.

**MY CODE:**

```
  if (isInternetPresent) 
{

    new AsyncTaskSync_MappingTableClass1(MainActivity.this).execute();

    new AsyncTaskSync_MappingTableClass2(MainActivity.this).execute();

    new AsyncTaskSync_MappingTableClass3(MainActivity.this).execute();

    new AsyncTaskSync_MappingTableClass4(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }
    else
    {
    Log.i("INFO"," No Internet.. :-(");
    }
```

Comment: you can also use runnable interface instead of asynctask and join method you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use [Android Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). This is some interface, that keep your threads, while that previous is executed.

For example. You user 10 Threads Runnables, (AsyncTask). But you understand, that run 10 threads - it's bad idea. So you want to create memory space for only 3 threads and save device performance. So should use interface that run first three threads, and! when some thread is executed, than you run next.

**Update!**
So you just add all your threads (10, 100 ....), and executor correct manage all task in memory. There are another constructors TheadPool.  Check documentation for more information. Cheers!

**Example:**

```
List<AsyncTask> listTask = new ArrayList<>();
....
//Add all your runnables interfaces

Executor ex = ThreadPoolExecutor.newFixedThreadPool(3); 

//Number of active threads - 3

for (int i = 10; i < 10; i++) {
ex.execute(listTask.get(i));
}
```

**Another example:**
Honestly, AsyncTask it's not best solution for background working. So executor support Runnable interfaces. So you need to read about java Thread and Runnable interfaces and android Executors, would be best solution for every time. In use Retrofit, RxJava, Volley and other realization. But java native methods simplest and stable.

**LAST UPDATE!** 
Please, visit [this resource, to read more](http://codetheory.in/android-java-executor-framework/).

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SimpleThreadPool extends Activity {

   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main)

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(String.valueOf(i));
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println('Finished all threads');
    }

}


public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String command;

    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this.command=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+' Start. Command = '+command);
        processCommand();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+' End.');
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.command;
    }
}
```

Result previous code.

```
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = 1
pool-1-thread-4 Start. Command = 3
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = 0
pool-1-thread-3 Start. Command = 2
pool-1-thread-5 Start. Command = 4
pool-1-thread-4 End.
pool-1-thread-5 End.
pool-1-thread-1 End.
pool-1-thread-3 End.
pool-1-thread-3 Start. Command = 8
pool-1-thread-2 End.
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = 9
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = 7
pool-1-thread-5 Start. Command = 6
pool-1-thread-4 Start. Command = 5
pool-1-thread-2 End.
pool-1-thread-4 End.
pool-1-thread-3 End.
pool-1-thread-5 End.
pool-1-thread-1 End.
Finished all threads
```

Comment: thanks, Can you add this Code Little Brief with  async Task Classes?

Comment: i am getting Error in your Code-cannot resolve method newfixedthreadpool

Comment: @Kumar i just wrote from memory. Update other example. Read more about that all.

Comment: Thank you very much . Friend :)

Comment: @Kumar Glad to help. Here is working android example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOyJZ6pn6pqQzZCdGt4T2pGbnc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to call one after the other, call the consecutive tasks in the onPostExecute() method. or else use interface callbacks.

Comment: how to implement interface callbacks ?

Comment: @PrithvirajShiroor it's bad solution.

Comment: @Kumar Create a Interface with required methods implement it in the class which you want to receive the call backs., create the object of the class and pass it to the method from which you will set the result like shown here...[link](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oreily/java/exp/ch05_08.htm)